# Accessing http on custom port in Azure HDInsight Cluster

Tags: azure, azure-hdinsight

I have successfully installed one of my application software on the Edge node of my Azure HDInsight Cluster 3.5. 
In ideal scenarios post the successful installation of the software, the web page associated with the software can be brought up at port# 8082 of edge node. 
However, all my attempts to access http://xxxxxxxxxx.azurehdinsight.net:8082 ends up with the following message "this site cannot be reached".

I have tried to access this port by giving the public ip address of the edge node as well. But it ended up with the same error.

The need here is to be able to access this (http://xxxxxxxxxx.azurehdinsight.net:8082) site from internet.
Thanks in advance for any help !

Answer (score 0):

we got this fixed by creating a sshTunnel (via putty). It seems by default only 22,23 and 443 ports are opened in HDInsight.